# What is the Debian version Parrot Security OS 3.11 based on?

Tags: debian, kernel, version, parrotsec

So I'm using `Parrot Security OS` (aka `ParrotSec`, `Parrot OS`), and I'm going to install VirtualBox, but as I go through the release note of `ParrotSec 3.11` (newest version) there isn't telling you that is it based on Debian 8 (Jessie) or 9 (Stretch)? It only said it started using Linux 4 kernel since ParrotSec 3.10. Who can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

The features table in [the download page](https://parrotsec.org/download/) used to indicate that Parrot 3.11 is based on Debian 10. Since Parrot host everything themselves ([the Parrot repository configuration includes only Parrot hosts](https://github.com/josegatica/parrot-docu-en/blob/master/20.-%20Mirrors%20List.md)), what you get depends on how often Parrot refreshes its packages from Debian; that appears to happen very often, so it seems appropriate to consider that Parrot is based on Debian 10 (even while the latter was still being developed and therefore changed often).

When downloading third-party software, you should choose versions for Debian 10 if available, 9 if not, or for later versions of Parrot, whatever Debian version they are based on.

To install VirtualBox, you can use the Debian package instead of Oracle’s:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

If you really want to install the Oracle package, [follow the instructions for “Debian-based Linux distributions”](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), using the appropriate release name (Buster for Debian 10).

[ParrotOS follows now a Long Term support-model](https://www.parrotsec.io/blog/2022-03-24-parrot-5.0-press-release/), based on [Debian Stable](https://www.debian.org/releases/), which as of Parrot 5.0 is Debian 11 (Bullseye). It's guaranteed to have no significant updates for at least two years, but the model differs from Debian’s LTS. Security tools are still updated following a rolling release model, *i.e.* updates are available as soon as they’re published.

Comment: Then what version of debian should I chose when I'm downloading shoftware? For example if you're downloading virtual box, which version should I chose?